# How to loop and replace in one string

Tags: python

I have this dictionary file:

```
{"device1": [["Cisco", "IDF01"]],
 "device2": [["Cisco", "IDF02"]],
 "device3": [["Cisco", "IDF03"]]
}
```

And I need to create the following html code based on that dictionary. I need to find out how many IDFs the dictionary file has. Because the dictionary file changes every week. so I need to loop through the dic, and extract all IDF numbers and create the following:
I need this output:

```
{{tabs labels="idf01=IDF01, idf02=IDF02, idf03=IDF03"/}}
```

so if DIC file had another row with IDF04, the output should include that.

I have this code:

```
with open("data-dic.txt", 'r') as dic:
        data = dic.read()
        dataDic = json.loads(data)
        dataDic = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(dataDic))

        for x,y in dataDic.items():
            array = {}
            for z in sorted(y):
                 if "IDF01" in z[1]:
                     createTabs ="""{{tabs labels="idf01=z[1]"/}}"""
```

but I have no idea how to append to this. Is this a correct way to do it? Please advise.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open("data-dic.txt", 'r') as dic:
    data = dic.read()
    dataDic = json.loads(data)
    dataDic = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(dataDic))
    n = len(dataDic)
    count = 0
    out = '{{tabs labels='
    for x, z in dataDic.items():
        if z[0][1].startswith("IDF"):
            if count < n - 1:
                out += f'"{z[0][1].lower()}={z[0][1]}", '
            else:
                out += f'"{z[0][1].lower()}={z[0][1]}"'
        count += 1
    out += '/}}'
```